# Переход по ссылкам и запись в файл

Tags: python, selenium

Задача: Читаем построчно урлы из файла и переходим по ним. Если НЕ 404 - идем дальше. Если 404 - пишем в лог и идем дальше.

Два вопроса: Как перебор ссылок и переход по ним заключить в функцию, чтобы не копипастить? И второй: Как сделать так, чтобы тест не падал при нахождении 404-й, а именно писал в файл и шел дальше?

Ниже кусок кода:

```
driver.get(line[0]) 
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
    raise Exception("Это страница 404")

driver.get(line[1])
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
    raise Exception("Это страница 404")

driver.get(line[2])
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
    raise Exception("Это страница 404")
```

Comment: Быстрое гугление показало, что селениум не вернет код http, поэтому можно предварительно проверить код через другую либу, используя `head`, вместо `get`: `for url in line:` `if requsts.head(url).status_code == 404: print("404! " + url)` `driver.get(url)`. Либо саму страницу анализировать на элементы, которые присутствуют на 404 странице

Comment: А так, тест у вас падает при выбрасывании исключения `raise Exception("Это страница 404")`, поэтому или не бросайте его, или ловите и обрабатывайте.

Comment: @gil9red  Код рабочий. Искуственно создал 40 и упало, только остановилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немножко подправил последний коммент и целый код вот какой вышел. Так же код смотрит битые ссылки и пишет в тот же файл. Выкладываю, вдруг кому поможет:

```
for url in line:
try:
    driver.get(url)
except WebDriverException:
    print("Incorrect URL: {}".format(url))
    write_to_file(r"Путь к записываемому файлу", "Incorrect URL: " + url)
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath):
    print('404: {}'.format(url))
    f = open('404.txt', 'w')
    write_to_file(r"Путь к записываемому файлу", "404: " + url)
    continue
```

Answer (score 2):

?

```
for url in line:
    driver.get(url)
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath):
        print('Здесь только пустота: {}'.format(url))
        continue
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_lines(driver, lines):
    for line in lines: #Переберем все строчки
        driver.get(line) #Обработаем текущую строку
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
            write_to_file(r"ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ", "Это страница 404 \n")


def write_to_file(filepath, s): #Функция записывает строку в файл
    with open(filepath, ‘a’) as f: #Добавим новую строчку в файл
        f.write(s)
```

*Примечание*: Наверное, стоит добавить что-нибудь к строке «Это страница 404», чтобы различать ссылки, но это на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Да, добавил к строке сам url. Спасибо всем за помощь

Comment: @СергейБогданов Если этот код решил вашу проблему, пометьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как правильный (если вдруг у кого-то будет такая же проблема). Спасибо!